# What happens on Moksha as per Bhagvad Gita?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, moksha

As per Bhagvad Gita, what happens at Moksha ? Does the person get merged in Krishna ? Does he get sharan of Krishna ?

What exactly is mentioned in Bhagvad Gita on Moksha ?

Comment: Different schools would have a different interpretation